# Populating Gridview from JSON response

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to populate Grid View from JSON response received from Async Task. Below is the activity file

```
public class OpenTableActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse{

    String serUri, method;
    OpenTableAdapter op;
    WebServiceAsyncTask webTask = new WebServiceAsyncTask(this);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.open_table);
        getTables();
        webTask.listener = this;

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new OpenTableAdapter(this,tableList));

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.opentableLinear);
        layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
                hideKeyboard(view);
                return false;
            }
        });



        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.table_home_btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(homeBtn);
    }

    public boolean getTables() {

        serUri = "tables.json";

        method = "get";
        WebServiceAsyncTask webServiceTask = new WebServiceAsyncTask(OpenTableActivity.this);
        webServiceTask.execute(serUri, method, this);

        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public void WriteJsonArray(JSONArray result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);


                String tabLabel = c.getString("tablabel");
                String tabStatus = c.getString("tabstatus");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put("table_name", tabLabel);
                map.put("table_status", tabStatus);

                tableList.add(map);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }}
```

The Adapter class to fill grid view is as below

```
public class OpenTableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    String orderNumber;
    OpenTableActivity openInstance;
    String tableLabel;
    String tableStatus;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tablist = null;

    public OpenTableAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tablelist ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        mContext = c;
        mInflater =  LayoutInflater.from(c);
        tablist = tablelist;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        openInstance = new OpenTableActivity();
        return openInstance.tableList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.button, 
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);   
           convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        HashMap<String, String> map = tablist.get(position);
            for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = mapEntry.getKey();
                String value = mapEntry.getValue();

                holder.btn.setText(key);


            return convertView;


    }



    static class ViewHolder
       {
         Button btn;
       } 

}
```

the interface class defined is as below:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {

    public void WriteJsonArray(JSONArray tableList);

}
```

The Async task class is as below

```
public class WebServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,JSONArray> {

    AsyncResponse listener;
    public WebServiceAsyncTask(){}
    public WebServiceAsyncTask(Context appcontext)
    {
        this.context=appcontext;
        listener = (AsyncResponse) this.context;
    }
    String serviceUrl;


    OpenTableActivity openInstance=new OpenTableActivity();
    CategoryActivity catAct; 
    private static JSONArray json = null;
    private Context context = null;
    private static JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        serviceUrl = (String) params[0];
        String method = (String) params[1];

         final HTTPHelper httph = new HTTPHelper(serviceUrl,context);

             json = httph.fetch();                        


         return json; 
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) { // invoked on the ui thread
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // dismiss progress dialog
    // update ui here


   super.onPostExecute(result);

       if (listener != null){
           listener.WriteJsonArray(result);
       }


}
```

On running this I am getting Stackoverflow error as soon as activity class is called. I tried many different options but still same error. Not sure what I am missing as unable to debug too as its giving error even before entering the activity class. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the StackOverflowException, identify the method that causes the recursion, eliminate the recursion. Please respect that StackOverflow (this site) is not your debugger.

Comment: I don't know why you use OpenTableActivity openInstance=new OpenTableActivity(); in both your adapter and AsyncTask.
 You can read more about how to use adapter and asynctask before using them like that!

Comment: That was done when I was trying different options to make this work. Thanks for pointing this. Will remove it as not required now.            @allprog : I understand this but I posted only after trying for several hours and still no luck.

Comment: At least add the stack trace to the question. Place break points in the code and execute step-by-step. Eclipse is a great help with that.

Comment: I tried doing that as well but it throws error as soon OpenTableActivity is called on pressing button. Its not even going to OnCreate Method. The error thrown is java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)  android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker.<init>(StrictMode.java:2225)  at android.os.StrictMode.trackActivity(StrictMode.java:1927)     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:755)                at com.example.roms.OpenTableActivity.<init>(OpenTableActivity.java:25)

Comment: @Gaurav why do you have this at the beginning  `WebServiceAsyncTask webTask = new WebServiceAsyncTask(this)` and also have this  `WebServiceAsyncTask webServiceTask = new WebServiceAsyncTask(OpenTableActivity.this);
        webServiceTask.execute(serUri, method, this)`; in `getTables()`

Comment: @Gaurav another mistake in getCount of adapter `openInstance = new OpenTableActivity();
        return openInstance.tableList.size()` should be replaced by `tablist.size()` also you should use the `tablist` in `getView`

Comment: @Gaurav i also suggest you post the entire code coz is suspect you doing it wrong in that part also

Comment: I created this for the interface class. Just removed it and ran again. The error is gone now.Thanks a lot Raghunandan. But still the grid is not being populated. Its fetching the result from server but not populating it in grid.

Comment: can you paste the url here and again you should set he adapter to your gridview after you fetch the data i don't think you are doing the same

Comment: url is http://192.168.1.3:3000"/tables.json  ...The Webservice Asynctaks object in getTables() is created to call asynctask class. SerUri is the url (tables.json) and method is to let know whether to post or get.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35582/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-gaurav)

Comment: @Gaurav try the below answer if it helps accept and upvote the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting solution. From the discussion

You need to move the below to  WriteJsonArray. Once you get the data you need to pass the same to the adapter class

```
    gridview.setAdapter(new OpenTableAdapter(this,tableList));
```

Replace your `getCount` by

```
@Override 
public int getCount() { 

return tablist.size(); 
}
```

In getview remove your for loop

```
HashMap<String,String> map = tablist.get(position); 
String value = map.get("key"); 
// make sure the key i right. "key" here is only an example. replace with right key
holder.btn.setText("value");
```

remove this

```
WebServiceAsyncTask webTask = new WebServiceAsyncTask(this); // at the beginnning
```

remove this from asynctask

```
OpenTableActivity openInstance=new OpenTableActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> waitForCompletion = new AsyncTask<Void, Void,   Boolean>() {

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
             dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        }

                @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                     }
     }
```

Comment: it is work properly in my project in Onpreexection() use like loading dialog box...onbackground() get your all data from json...and onpostexecution() dismiss loadin dialog box or set you data or whatever u want to do next...it will work properly...

Comment: i don't think so. there are other mistakes in ops question that should be rectified. this answer does not help at all. check this discussion between me and op you will now yourself

Comment: your project is different from op's question. this does not answer the question posted